# Does the kernel of $f:\operatorname{End}_A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ contains all non-automorphisms?

Tags: ring-theory

Let:

1. $A$ is a non-trivial abelian group
2. $\operatorname{End}_A$ is the ring of endomorphisms of $A$
3. $\operatorname{Aut}_A$ is the set of automorphisms of $A$
4. $f:\operatorname{End}_A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is a unital ring homomorphism
5. $\ker(f)$ is the kernel of $f$

We can prove that $\operatorname{Aut}_A\cap \ker(f)=\emptyset$. Does the same hold for the complements, i.e. $\overline{\operatorname{Aut}_A}\cap\overline{\ker(f)}=\emptyset$? Can we at least say that $\phi\notin\ker(f)$ implies that $\phi$ has the left or right inverse?

Comment: The first one would mean ${\rm Aut}_A=(\ker(f))^\complement$, which is rarely the case. For the second one, consider the constant $1$ map, that is the zero element of ${\rm End}_A$.

Comment: To your last question: the zero endomorphism always belong to $Ker(f)$, by definition of ring homomorphism, but it is never left nor right invertible...

Comment: @Simone thanks for the comment, I've edited. I've meant $\notin$

Comment: Are your ring homomorphisms required to be unital?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\mathbb{Z}$, then $\operatorname{End}(A)=\mathbb{Z}$. You can then take $f$ to be the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$, and any element which is neither $0$ nor $\pm 1$ is neither in the kernel nor invertible.

Comment: We're talking about Abelian groups here.

Comment: Oops;  quite right.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are good, but I want to point out that this actually *never* happens.

Suppose for contradiction that $f : \operatorname{End}_A \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\ker(f)$ contains all non-automorphisms. Since $\ker(f)$ is a proper ideal of $\operatorname{End}_A$, it does not contain any elements of $\operatorname{Aut}_A$. This means that $\ker(f) = \operatorname{End}_A \setminus \operatorname{Aut}_A$. The existence of $f$ tells us that $\operatorname{End}_A \neq 0$, so we conclude $\operatorname{End}_A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\ker(f)$. Now $\operatorname{img}(f) \cong \operatorname{End}_A/\ker(f)$ must be a division ring. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ has no division subrings (these would be fields of characteristic $0$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ does not embed in $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: This is very nice

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = \mathbb Z$ and $\chi: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z, \chi(z) = 2z$. Set $f: \operatorname{End}(A) \to \mathbb Z, f(\phi) = \phi(1)$. Then $f$ is a ring homomorphism because $f(\phi \circ \psi) = \phi \circ \psi(1) = \phi(\psi(1)) = \phi(n) = mn$, where $\phi(z) = mz$ and $\psi(z) = nz$. Moreover, $\chi \notin \ker f$.

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Comment: @ElmarGuseinov It's the same example that Captain Lama gave; I only posted it somewhat earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you prescribe that a ring morphism sends the unit to the unit, so that the map is surjective. This implies in particular that $\ker(f) $ is a *proper* ideal: if it was all of $End_A$, the image would be $0$.

The answer to the first question is yes: the automorphisms are by definition the units of the ring, and they can't intersect a proper ideal.

The answer to the second question is no as it is shown by the following example. Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $ f: End_A \to \mathbb{Z} $ be defined by
$$f(\varphi) = \varphi(1) $$
Then the endomorphisms $\mu_n(x) =nx $ for $n\ge 2$ are not automorphisms and they are mapped to $n$ by $f$ (so they don't belong to the kernel) .

Comment: Thanks for the example!